# getting user as null in firebase auth

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to listen to the change in the document but I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
```

this is my javascript code

```
var user = auth.currentUser;
db.collection('user-intro').doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(function(doc){
    console.log(doc.data());
})
```

where I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `auth.currentUser` gets the user before the user is signed in.

This typically happens if the user has just signed in, or if you refresh the page. While Firebase restores the authentication state on a page reload, this takes a bit of time as it needs to check the credentials against the server.

To ensure you code only runs after the authentication state has been restored, you'll want to wrap it in an `onAuthStateChanged` handler:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChange(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    db.collection('user-intro').doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(function(doc){
      console.log(doc.data());
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`auth.currentUser` is null.  That means no user is signed in at the moment you called it.  You need to check for that case before using the `user` variable that you assigned it to.

Comment: That's not what the sdk is telling you as you access currentUser. Maybe you should use a listener instead so you know that the SDK is telling you the user is known.  It won't be available right away on a new page load:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user